# Any way for localized ABPersonViewController?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Can't get any information about localized ABPersonViewController...

I use Russian language on my iPod but when I call ABPersonViewController it always appears in English. I check other apps in AppStore - the same result.

Is there any way to call localized ABPersonViewController?

thx

Comment: yes, Russian only so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ABPersonViewController [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> displayedProperties Optional.
>   Identifies the set of properties (such
>   as name or telephone number) of
>   displayedPerson the receiver displays.
>
> @property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray
>   *displayedProperties Discussion The default value of this property is
>   NULL.
>
> The properties are specified using an
>   array of NSNumber objects representing
>   ABPropertyID values.
>
> To have the receiver display a single
>   property for displayedPerson, such as
>   telephone number, set
>   displayedProperties to an array with a
>   single value, such as
>   kABPersonPhoneProperty.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Declared In
>   ABPersonViewController.h

From ABPerson [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210)

> > ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName Returns the localized name of a person
> >     property
>
> CFStringRef
>   ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName (
>   ABPropertyID property ); Parameters
>   property The person property whose
>   localized name is being returned.
>   Return Value The localized name of
>   property.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Declared In ABPerson.h

Edit,

The internationalization is made automat for you, You just need to create in your bundle Directory "ru.lproj" directory.

Then from File - > New File - > Resource -> Strings File.
Save it in ru.lproj with "Localizable.strings". And there you go.

Comment: as I get from docs and examples - ABPersonCopyLocalizedPropertyName just return CFString with localized name of some person property. I think I can't use this string to change property label on ABPersonViewController.

Comment: You can post an bug report to apple to get an official answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

Project->Info->Localization->+  choose your language.
That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "Localization native development region" to your region in the .plist file.